# What is the derivative of a delayed function in discrete time?

Tags: derivatives, partial-differential-equations, control-theory, discrete-time

How do you calculate such derivative?

$$\frac{d\ \ x_{1}\left(k+1\right)\ }{d\ \ x_{1}(k)}$$

Sorry for the probably silly question but I have been having some serious trouble with this

Answer (score 2):

I've never really seen this notation, but it probably refers to recurrences of the form $x (k+1) = g(x(k))$. In this framework, I'd say that
$$
\frac{d x(k+1)}{d x(k)} := g'(x(k)).
$$